# Есть ли способ получить данные о текущей подключенной сети Wi-Fi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, wifi

Я хотел бы получить информацию о текущей сети `Wi-Fi` через `python`, но как это можно реализовать?
Я хочу получить данные о имени сети и ее скорости, при чем выполнять это только на `Windows`

Comment: Наверняка это зависит от операционки

Comment: @AlexeyTen для примера давайте рассматривать Windows

Comment: какую конкретно информацию ты хочешь получить?

Comment: @Grundy имя сети, скорость интернета и в принципе все

Comment: @Walle. добавь это в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью [edit] под вопросом

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте
https://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/

Вроде бы появилась версия и для Windows (сам не пробовал, но смотрим на сайт https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/)

Или еще вариант (для Windows) https://pypi.org/project/ifaddr/

Со "скорость интернета" есть нюансы. Для того, что-бы посчитать реальную скорость надо что-то прочесть из интернета, определить объем прочитанного и поделить на время выполнения закачки. В принципе, все программы определяющие скорость так и работают. Поэтому можно это довольно просто написать самому.

Или использовать АPI каких-либо готовых пакетов измерения. И первое, что приходит в голову, конечно, speedtest. У него есть свой открытый API, до которого можно добраться (windows - только 64 битная):

https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli

https://xn--90aeniddllys.xn--p1ai/pyatiminutka-python-test-skorosti-interneta-v-5-strok/